# Cannot convert from Collection<> to List<>

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to validate a result from a library (Panache / Hibernate using Quarkus) by passing the object to a "validator", where the validator validates that the result is not empty and subsequently returns the passed object back to the caller.

In this example, `listAll()` is from `PanacheEntityBase` and simply returns a list of `Employee` objects. If this `List` is empty, as in, there are no results in the result set, it does not throw an exception. So to avoid having an empty / null check in every call, I am writing the follow convenience class to validate  all results.

In my validator:

```java
public class ResultValidator {

    public static <T> Collection<T> validate(Collection<T> result, Class<T> type) throws EmptyResultException {
        if (result.isEmpty()) {
            throw new EmptyResultException();
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

The caller would invoke this like:

```java
return ResultValidator.validate(listAll(), Employee.class);
```

Rather, I'm having to upcast:

```java
return (List<Employee>) ResultValidator.validate(listAll(), Employee.class);
```

The code above, that invokes `validate`, results in a compiler error `Cannot convert from Collection<> to List<>`. Unless I'm upcasting to `List<>` or explicitly defining `List<>` type in my `validate` implementation, I will get this error.

What do I need to change in my `validate(Collection, Class)` implementation to avoid upcasting or declaring an explicit type?

Comment: which error you get? Where does listAll() come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your intent is to return 'self', then:

```
public static <T, C extends Collection<T>> C validate(C result, Class<T> type) {
   // note that requiring a `Class<T>` is a code smell...

   if (result.isEmpty()) throw new EmptyResultException();
   return result;
}

List<String> list = ...;
list = validate(list, String.class);
```

now works fine, but note that it is not possible to *make* a new `C` instance. You're either returning `result` straight up, and therefore the fact that `validate` returns at all is, at best, some code/API convenience but not inherently useful, or, you can't use this, and you'd need a 'make a new collection' factory. That would get you to:

```
public static <T, C extends Collection<T>> C validate(C result, Class<T> type, Supplier<C> collectionMaker) {
 ... 
}
```

Where the caller would have to provide something. e.g.:

```
List<String> list = ...;
validate(list, String.class, () -> new ArrayList<String>());
```

Comment: You are correct to say it's purely out of convenience. It is a large project with a lot of hands, and we've noticed there have been a few different approaches to dealing with empty results (this is just one example). I'm looking into standardizing a way we verify results before they reach the client.

Comment: I was thinking about your answer and am wondering about your comment `Class<T> is a code smell`. I'm hoping you can elaborate on this, as I've seen it used in several popular libraries / frameworks. I want to avoid code smells! I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Depends on what the intent is of that Class. If it is to make new instances, you should be using a factory. If it is to reify generics, then use something else - classes cannot represent e.g. `List<String>`, only raw List. If it's anything else, Class is probably fine (not a code smell).